# c++ pass char array to void function

Tags: c++

Task is to change every uppercase letter to lowercase and vice versa, and increase every number by 1, and change 9 for 0.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void modif ( char*& arr){
    for (int i=0;arr[i]!=0;i++)
        if ('a'<=arr[i] && arr[i]<='z'){
            arr[i]=char(((int)arr[i])-32);
        }
        else if ('A'<=arr[i] && arr[i]<='Z'){
            arr[i]=char(((int)arr[i])+32);
        }
        else if ('0'<=arr[i] && arr[i]<='8'){
            arr[i]=char(((int)arr[i])+1);
        }
        else if (arr[i]== '9'){
            arr[i]=char(((int)arr[i])-8);
        }
}

int main() {
    char * s=new char [100];
    cin.getline (s, 100);
    void modif (char * s);

    cout << s  << endl;
    delete [] s;
}
```

I can get it to work without void function, but can't with it

Comment: `void modif(char* s);` doesn't call the function, it just declares it.

Comment: @onslow Welcome to Stack Overflow! If your problem is solved, and you no longer need help, please mark one of the answers accepted by clicking the grey check mark next to it. This would let other site visitors know that you are no longer actively seeking help with the issue, without reading through the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this so that you actually call the function:

```
int main() {
    char * s=new char [100];
    cin.getline (s, 100);
    // void modif (char * s); // removed line
    modif(s);                 // new line

    cout << s  << endl;
    delete [] s;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
void modif (char * s);
```

is a function declaration, you want to call it with:

```
modif(s);
```

also you dont need `char*&` in your function, `char*` will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

`void modif (char * s);` is a *forward declaration*. It is unnecessary in your example, because `modif` is defined above its point of invocation. You would need it if you wanted to move `modif` to a place in the file below `main`, or to a different file altogether:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char * s=new char [100];
    cin.getline (s, 100);
    void modif (char*&); // Forward declaration
    modif(s);            // Call
    cout << s  << endl;
    delete [] s;
}

void modif ( char*& arr){
    for (int i=0;arr[i]!=0;i++)
    if ('a'<=arr[i] && arr[i]<='z'){
       arr[i]=char(((int)arr[i])-32);
    }

   else if ('A'<=arr[i] && arr[i]<='Z'){
       arr[i]=char(((int)arr[i])+32);
    }
    else if ('0'<=arr[i] && arr[i]<='8'){
       arr[i]=char(((int)arr[i])+1);
    }
    else if (arr[i]== '9'){
       arr[i]=char(((int)arr[i])-8);
    }
}
```

Forward declaration is a promise to the compiler that there is going to be a definition of your function somewhere else. This way the compiler knows how to make a call if you choose to call your function. Note that the signatures in the declaration and in the definition must match.

The call, on the other hand, looks like this:

```
modif(s);
```

Here, you tell the compiler that you want to invoke function `modif`, and pass the current value of `s` for its formal parameter called `arr`.